# create SAML assertion from AzureAD without user interaction?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, saml, sap-successfactors

I've got a requirement for an SAP integration to authenticate my identity governance app via a SAML assertion (currently just using basic auth). I wouldn't consider myself an authentication expert, but I'm pretty sure this is not a common pattern for API authn/authz. Here's the guidance from SAP:

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SUCCESSFACTORS_PLATFORM/d599f15995d348a1b45ba5603e2aba9b/4e27e8f6ae2748ab9f23228dd6a31b06.html

I'm using AzureAD, and the only way I can think of to get that SAML token with all their requirements is by using ROPC, which I'm not fond of doing. Is there any other way around this?